# List of events in facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there a way to query all the events listed in facebook? I see all API's provide a way to query information specific to a user or by an Application ID but not sure if its possible to query generic data such as a list of all events listed in facebook by various users or businesses/organizations.

Answer (score 0):

You can examine the connections between objects using the URL structure  graph.facebook.com/ID/CONNECTION_TYPE.

here's an example from the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) :

https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?access_token=2227470867|2.gGtACmeQGq51Pxqu8pGnlg__.3600.1298570400-590157628|NdIFut8zccPqJoVQHcfRGI5GX6A

Comment: Hm, that doesn't really answer your question... sorry.

Comment: But I think I can use "Searching" feature of Graph API. As per the documentation:: You can search over all public objects in the social graph with https://graph.facebook.com/search. The format is:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE

Comment: well, you can search public events this way. you still need a query parameter though, I cant see any way around that. In your question you said for 'various users', if you have a list of users you can get their events individually and put it all together yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Yeas,, You have to download the SDK from facebook

SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/

(SDK available for different platforms).

Create a facebook app in facebook for your site, it will generates an **application id** and **application secret**, using that details to **configure the SDK**. And you can now able to query the events db using the sdk and get events from facebook (Profile or a page).